# How to create a service connection to my local service?

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-service-hooks

I have a "ABCD" web service running on a machine. I have TFS and agent running on another system of same network. Via a browser I am able to access the ABCD web service(such as https://<computername>:<portNumber> or https://<ip>:<portNumber>) from the machine where TFS is installed.

Now I want to create a a service connection to my web service so as to call the APIs. On Verifying the Service connection via "TestConnection" dataSources, am getting the following error.

*Error Message: An error occurred while sending the request..
Note: Verification may fail if the URL is not accessible from Azure DevOps Server. However, it might still be valid and accessible from the agent that executes the build or release.*

As it says, I am able to access the APIs from the agent that executes the build and release, but I need this APIs to populate the picklist in my task(for dataSourceBindings). How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly caused your service based URL is a local address, such as http://computername:8080 (or http://ip:8080). **But the URL can’t be reached by others.**

Do below things to check if local URL can be used:

1. Turn off any VPN (if you have )
2. Check your firewall settings. Temporarily turn off firewall for your local machine, check if this do the trick.

If all above is still not work. For further troubleshooting, you could also use fiddler trace capture packages or use F12 (when you create service connection in Azure DevOps web portal) and check if there are some useful information.